# Can I check one specific pixelrow instead of just one pixel in python with pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

At the moment I have a function that goes: if pyautogui.pixel(x,y) [0] == whatever. But the only specific part I need is the X value. But for the Y-Value I'd like to check every pixel. So that I check a Row. Is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.